# setup multiple node in bigchaindb with mongodb

Tags: blockchain, bigchaindb

I have set up a local server of bigchaindb and done some blockchain operations on it. But in a production environment, I need to set up a cluster of it so how can I set up multiple nodes or cluster of a bigchaindb server using MongoDB as backend?

Answer (score 0):

In BigchainDB 2.0, MongoDB is the only backend database option. You can use any of the cluster deployment options, including:

- the new one where each node uses one VM and all software is run as processes: https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/master/simple-network-setup.html
- the old one where each node runs on its own Kubernetes cluster: https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/master/production-deployment-template/index.html
- your own custom deployment process.